# C++ - using ostream in my own class

Tags: c++, windows, io

I'm having problems using a ostream in my logger class. For some reason, the std::endl is never printed out and so no newline is added. I am sure there is something wrong, I'm having problems trying to understand how to use my ostream in my own classes so I have probably done something fundamentaly wrong.

```
class MyStreamBuf : public std::streambuf
{
    public:
    MyStreamBuf() : std::streambuf() 
    {

    }
};

class MyLogger : public std::ostream
{
public:
    MyLogger(MyStreamBuf* buf) : std::ostream(buf) { mBuf = buf; }
    ~MyLogger() { delete mBuf; }

    template <typename T>
    inline MyLogger& operator << (T const& value)
    {
#ifdef _WIN32 || _WIN64
        std::cout << value;
#endif

        return *this;
    }

    inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& (*f)(std::ostream&))
    {

        return f(*this);
    }

    MyStreamBuf* mBuf;
};



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyStreamBuf* buf = new MyStreamBuf();
    MyLogger logger(buf);
    logger << "kekekek" << "asdf: " << 23 << std::endl;
    logger << "kekekek" << "asdf: " << 23 << std::endl;;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
kekekekasdf: 23kekekekasdf: 23
```

Comment: `endl` isn't a constant or anything like that. Rather, it's a function, like `std::endl(std::cout)`. You might make specific arrangements for that.

Comment: Why not just `std::streambuf` is implemented? On that way you could do something like: `MyStreamBuf* buf = new MyStreamBuf(); std::ostream logger(buf);` You should implement just 3 functions: `sync`, `overflow` and `underflow`.

Comment: You print everything to `cout`, but not `endl`! (first overload triggered for values, last for `endl` and first contains `cout << value`, while last does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& (*f)(std::ostream&))
{
        std::cout << f;
        return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You got the basic approach right when using a custom stream buffer class. However, this is the place you want to implement the specific logic rather than in the class derived from `std::ostream`!

Just to explain what currently happens: when you call `f(*this)` the function `f()` is called with the `std::ostream` base which receives the output and gets `flush()` called. Your class is entirely out of the picture.

Here is what you should do:
 * remove the output operators from your `MyLogger` class
 * implement `overflow()` in you stream buffer to deal with overflowing its buffer (e.g. send characters somewhere or increase the buffer)
 * implement `sync()` to send any buffered characters and do whatever else you need to do when the stream is flushed
 * probably `MyLogger` should own the stream buffer and set its vase up properly; typically that's all a class derived from `std::ostream` does

There ate plenty examples on how this looks like out there. Search for `streambuf` and James Kanze or me to locate a couple.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the endl somewhere. By doing `f(*this)` you're trying to send it to yourself, but your object doesn't have the necessary methods to do that. If you look in `#include <ostream>`, the function `endl` uses the function `put` to put a `\n` in the stream and then flushes it.

You need to write the end line somewhere. For example if you're writing to `cout` then you can do

```
(*f)(std::cout);
```